# Error：Nothing PROVIDES ‘opensll-micmy-mod’ when it adds the new layer

Tags: yocto, yocto-layer

All

I build the board s32g274ardb2 to use BSP36.0, it  can make the image. Now I want to add new layer to project, so I  setup the new layaer meta-mylayer, I create the .bb .c and makefile.
Then I add the meta-mylayer path to  bblayers.conf.
Then  I  build errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNJa4.png)
Here it is the location of the meta-mylayer:
I put the code and config in it.
Then I change the build_32g274ardb2/conf/bblayers.conf
Then I add IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " my-mod"  to local.conf
Here it is my build configuration and  the meta-mylayers files.
At last. I bitbake fsl-image-auto, then it reports errors. I do not know what it is wrong.Please help me to find it.

Comment: What does your layer configuration look like? Did you follow the instructions for creating a new layer and recipe using `devtool`? [Reference](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/devtool-reference.html)...

Answer (score 0):

You should show your local.conf. But it looks like you haven't added a space properly when appending `my-mod`, so you are building the last added item `openssl-misc` concantenated with `my-mod` so it's trying to build `openssl-miscmy-mod` which doesn't exist and fails.

Make sure there is a space in your conf e.g.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " vim"
```

And then double check you have added your layer with

```
bitbake-layers show-layers
```

And you can show recipes the layer provides with and check that `my-mod` exists with:

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes -l meta-mylayer
```